# Why is entangling injectable with class that uses it a bad practice?

Tags: php, static, factory-method

I have had this argument for a while, because I have noticed some people prefer "readable" code over properly structured one. So in the example I am showing, basically I have this `Mapper` class in which different `Mappable` instances are injected and the Mapper uses the instances to know how to map some data. The question here is, why is it a bad practice to do so. I suspect that the problems are: the method is static, the factory is in the wrong class, making the Mapper hard coupled to the `Map` classes.

```
interface Mappable {
    public function getMetaData();
    public function setMetaData(array $metaData);
}

class BaseMap implements Mappable {
    protected $metaData = [];

    public function getMetaData() {
        return $this->metaData;
    }   

    public function setMetaData(array $metaData) {
        $this->metaData = $metaData;
    }

    /**
     * Possible Code Smell
     */
    public static function getNewMapper() {
        return new Mapper(new static);
    }
}

class MapA extends BaseMap {
    protected $metaData = [
        'backField1' => 'frontField1',
        'backField2' => 'frontField2'
    ];
}

class MapB extends BaseMap {
    protected $metaData = [
        'backFieldA' => 'frontFieldA',
        'backFieldB' => 'frontFieldB'
    ];
}

class Mapper {
    private $map;

    public function __construct(Mappable $map) {
        $this->setMap($map);
    }

    public function setMap(Mappable $map) {
        $this->map = $map;
    }

    public function parseData($dataRow) {
        $metaData = $this->map->getMetaData();
        $parsedDataRow = [];

        foreach($dataRow as $columnName => $columnValue) {
            if(isset($metaData[$columnName]))
                $parsedDataRow[$metaData[$columnName]] = $columnValue;
        }

        return $parsedDataRow;
    }
}

// Probably correct
$mapper = new Mapper(new MapA());
print_r($mapper->parseData(['backField1' => 'foo1', 'backField2' => 'bar1']));

$mapper->setMap(new MapB());
print_r($mapper->parseData(['backFieldA' => 'fooA', 'backFieldB' => 'barB']));

// Possible Code Smell
print_r(MapA::getNewMapper()->parseData(['backField1' => 'foo1', 'backField2' => 'bar1']));
print_r(MapB::getNewMapper()->parseData(['backFieldA' => 'fooA', 'backFieldB' => 'barB']));
```

**UML class diagram:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not a PHP expert, but I can read the code.

When I see this code

```
// Probably correct
$mapper = new Mapper(new MapA());
print_r($mapper->parseData(['backField1' => 'foo1', 'backField2' => 'bar1']));
```

Then I think to myself, why do I need to instantiate a `Mapper` with `MapA`.
I would want to have 1 class that both holds the data and knows how to map.
I would want `class Mapper` to extend `BaseMap` and `MapA` to extend `Mapper`

Then, I can simply

```
$mapper = new MapA();
print_r($mapper->parseData(['backField1' => 'foo1', 'backField2' => 'bar1']));
```

Granted, `MapA` might not be the best name, you could have used the name of the real mapping method.

Edit:

The counter argument for that is that this leaves the current design flexible, one could use different `Mapper` classes. My counter counter argument; that feature is not intuitive because the only factory method you have only returns `Mapper`.

That means that your approach is not caller friendly *and* not intuitive. If you want to keep the design flexible, then you should remove the static factory method. You could replace it with a comment that points out that this can be used by different mappers.

Finally, you should design with [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) in mind, refactoring for new requirements is okay.

Comment: I am sorry but I must disagree with you, since the idea is that I use inversion of control and dependency injection to be able to easily test and swap Mappers and Maps. Let's say I want to parse the data for half of the maps in a different way. If I use my way, I just need to create a new Mapper class that does the mapping in a different way and just pass the maps as parameters to the constructor. Otherwise, using your way, I have to implement two additional Maps that extend the new Mapper to be able to run, test, exchange when I need it to. I am decoupling the code, you are coupling it.

Comment: Ha! You tied `getNewMapper` straight into `BaseMap`. I guess you answered your own question as to why that is bad then.

Comment: Well if you read my question well, you can see that I have mentioned that, and I know it is bad, but I am looking for other reasons why it might be bad.

Comment: My point is that your design is not *user friendly* because I need to do more, and not *intuitive* because while it allows to be used with multiple mappers that is nowhere clearly expressed in your code.

Comment: How would you make it more clear then?

Answer (score 1):

The other problem i see with your code is your inheritance is making contracts with classes it should not need to and is really breaking all oop practices.  This approach allows for less code and cleaner code but also follows the convention of grouped functionality and multiple inheritance.

```
interface Mappable {
    public function getMetaData();
    public function setMetaData(array $metaData);
}

abstract class BaseMap implements Mappable {
    protected $metaData = [];

    public function getMetaData() {
        return $this->metaData;
    }   

    public function setMetaData(array $metaData) {
        $this->metaData = $metaData;
    }
}

abstract class Mapper extends BaseMap{
    private $map;

    public function setMap($map) {
        $this->map = $map;
    }

    public function parseData($dataRow) {
        $metaData = $this->getMetaData();
        $parsedDataRow = [];

        foreach($dataRow as $columnName => $columnValue) {
            if(isset($metaData[$columnName]))
                $parsedDataRow[$metaData[$columnName]] = $columnValue;
        }

        return $parsedDataRow;
    }
}

class MapA extends Mapper {
    protected $metaData = [
        'backField1' => 'frontField1',
        'backField2' => 'frontField2'
    ];
}

class MapB extends Mapper {
    protected $metaData = [
        'backFieldA' => 'frontFieldA',
        'backFieldB' => 'frontFieldB'
    ];
}


/* i think the benifits speak for them selfs */
// less code
// less objects 
// clean and readable
// easy to use
$mapA  = new MapA();
$mapA->parseData(['backField1' => 'foo1', 'backField2' => 'bar1']);

$mapB  = new MapB();
$mapB->parseData(['backField1' => 'foo1', 'backField2' => 'bar1']);
```